# How to make a view based on selected dimensions from multiple drop downs

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to create a single view that gives me  total number of students in terms of gender and age based on their PASS/FAIL grade in each subject .

My schema and dataset  is below .

```
 (id,name,age,Gender,english_grade,Mathematics_grade,Physics_grade,chemistry_grade,grade_ind)

   100  Steve   14  MALE    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    Y
   101  Edward  15  MALE    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   102  Andy    15  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   103  Kim     16  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   104  Tammy   14  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   105  Sue     15  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   106  Chen    15  MALE    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   107  Kim     16  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   108  Jim     14  MALE    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   109  Annie   15  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   110  Anna    15  FEMALE  PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   111  Royce   16  MALE    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   112  Mike    14  MALE    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   113  Peter   15  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   114  Board   15  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    PASS    PASS    Y
   115  Andrew  16  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   116  William 14  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   117  Santa   15  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   118  Sandy   15  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   119  Danny   16  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   120  Melisa  14  FEMALE  FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   121  Merlin  15  FEMALE  FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   122  Betsy   15  FEMALE  FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
   123  Bill    16  MALE    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    FAIL    N
```

I have created 4 drop downs using Parameters but don't know how to apply calculation field for those.

[image]

So, Now as Per the above selection I want a view that gives me total number of students  in terms of gender  who get PASS in Chemistry and English and Physics but FAIL in Maths.

Basically I want to apply a calculation as

```
 IF(chemistry = 'PASS' AND English ='PASS' AND Physics = 'PASS' AND Maths ='FAIL')
```

Similarly Based on respective selection from each  of these 4 drop down  I want my view to be reflected.

some other possible selections are

```
  IF(chemistry = 'PASS' AND English ='FAIL' AND Physics = 'FAIL' AND Maths ='FAIL')

 IF(chemistry = 'FAIL' AND English ='PASS' AND Physics = 'PASS' AND Maths ='FAIL')

 IF(chemistry = 'PASS' AND English ='PASS' AND Physics = 'PASS' AND Maths ='PASS')
```

I tried the below calculation field, but it is not showing correct view.

```
CASE [chemistry]
WHEN 'PASS' then [Chemistry Grade]
WHEN 'FAIL' then [Chemistry Grade]
ELSE ''
END
```

Any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try turning it into a sum, rather than count. Try something like this as a starting point:

```
SUM(IF(chemistry = 'PASS' AND English ='PASS' AND Physics = 'PASS' AND Maths ='FAIL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```